# Thread pool that also uses the calling thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture, threadpool

Is there any thread pool implementation that also allows to use the calling thread for execution?

Some background - I have a service that needs to call lots of dependent services (and do some work with their results). My service is massively parallel and might use up to 1000 threads serving concurrent requests (really, I'm not kidding).

A common pattern for parallel processing is, of course, a shared pool of background threads that is used to farm out the work from the main thread. It also has a fundamental problem of exhaustion, if each of 1000 service threads submits a long-running request then it's extremely easy to completely exhaust all of the pool's capacity.

Another classic solution is to use a private thread pool for each of the service threads. It's not very appealing, since I won't be able to make these private pools large enough.

So my idea is to use a special type of a thread pool executor that runs tasks in the calling thread and opportunistically uses the background thread pool to run tasks if it has free capacity. This way I can guarantee that the calling thread will make some progress in any case, even if the background pool is exhausted.

Does anybody know of such thread pool implementation?

Comment: Create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a bounded queue and a [`CallerRunsPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html).

Comment: This would work. It'd be still nice to run the tasks inside the caller thread during normal processing, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Though it isn't very clear from the question, it sounds like the threads are mostly blocking waiting for responses from other services. This isn't a very productive use of these threads. A large number of threads often causes the scheduler operate [inefficiently](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/sample_chapter/article.php/c13533/Why-Too-Many-Threads-Hurts-Performance-and-What-to-do-About-It.htm).

Alternatively, you can think about using asynchronous sockets with completion handlers. This avoids the blocking i/o, and calls handlers in your code where you can respond to i/o events occurring in the channel.

This ultimately means that you can reduce massively the number of threads in your application, and *should* improve performance.

Comment: Yes, threads spend most of the time blocked on waiting for network replies and most of exhaustion scenarios happen when one of the dependent services becomes too slow.

Unfortunately, the SDKs that I'm using for these services are all synchronous (this is Java, after all) and I can't spend a lot of time rewriting them into async event loops.

Comment: Sounds like it just might be worth the effort though, if not immediately, then something to consider in the future?... Thread per socket is not the best approach here IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to place a task queue between the calling thread(s) and the thread pool. Every request is placed on the queue, and workers process tasks in the queue in turn. When a task is complete notification is sent back to the calling thread.

Using this mechanism, you can always ensure that tasks will eventually be processed.